# Problem with 301 redirects due to URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I've got a new site setup using CMSMadeSimple (PHP based) but I'm having problems 301 redirecting the old site URLs with the new setup.

I'm using a standard .htaccess file for the CMS which translates SEO friendly URLs like http://www.example.com/test.html into http://www.example.com?page=test, but I also need to redirect old URLs (ASP site) in this file.

My current .htaccess is shown below, the line I've tried to add is

```
redirect 301 /test.asp http://www.example.com/test.html
```

but when I do this the page redirects to http://www.example.com/test.html?page=test.asp not http://www.example.com/test.html as required

```
# BEGIN Optional settings

# Turns off directory browsing
# not absolutely essential, but keeps people from snooping around without 
# needing empty index.html files everywhere
Options -Indexes

# Deny access to config.php
# This can be useful if php ever breaks or dies
# Use with caution, this may break other functions of CMSms that use a config.php
# file.  This may also break other programs you have running under your CMSms
# install that use config.php.  You may need to add another .htaccess file to those
# directories to specifically allow config.php.
<Files "config.php">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Sets your 403 error document
# not absolutely essential to have, 
# or you may already have error pages defined elsewhere
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden403.shtml

# No sense advertising what we are running
ServerSignature Off

# END Optional Settings

# BEGIN CMSMS and Rewrite Rules
# Make sure you have Options FollowSymLinks
# and Allow on

RewriteEngine On

# Might be needed in a subdirectory
#RewriteBase /

# URL Filtering helps stop some hack attempts
#IF the URI contains a "http:"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "["
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \[ [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "]"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \] [OR]
#OR if the URI contains a "<script>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
#OR script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
#OR any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L] 
# END Filtering

# CMSMS Rewriting
# Set assume mod_rewrite to true in config.php and clear CMSMS cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
# END CMSMS

# END Rewrite rules
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rewrite rule just needs to be written a little differently:

```
RewriteRule ^test.asp$ http://www.example.com/test.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

That works for me.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had trouble with this until I put the 301 redirects at the beginning of all my other redirect rules. This syntax was the one that finally worked though.

Comment: You were rewriting to an SEO/SEF format, which you then need to rewrite to the final "dynamic" format. You either have to do it first, or rewrite directly to the final format.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the following rule instead:

```
RewriteRule test.asp http://www.example.com/test.html [NC,R=301,L]
```